# Move semantic and multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm currently using c++11 standard and here is my problem.

I have a code where I build a struct and pass it to a class for initialization purpose only.

I used move semantic to avoid duplicating the data structure.

This class inherits multiple classes needs all or part of the struct and stores references to it/its components.

Here is an example:

```
class ConcreteClass : public BaseClassA, public BaseClassB
{
public:
    ConcreteClass(Data&& data)
        : BaseClassA(data),
          BaseClassB(data),
          _data(std::move(data)) // How could I store data in _data and forward _data reference to parent classes ?
    {
    }

    /* Class functions here */

private:
    const Data _data;
};

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    Data dat = { i, "test", std::make_shared<std::string>("test2") };
    ConcreteClass instance(std::move(dat));

    /* Do stuff with instance */

    return 0;
}
```

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5425d93159cf5b9) is a full example.

As expected, the shared shared_pointer and reference stored are consistent.
The problem being reference on instances (`Data::Str` member in this case)

How could I store data in _data and forward _data reference to parent classes?

**Extra question**

Is the default rvalue reference constructor sufficient?

Comment: Do you control BaseClassA and BaseClassB?

Comment: Short answer: No.  I can hardly modify those

Comment: You can't simultaneously move `data` to three distinct objects.   It is necessary to copy it at least twice, or for the base classes to store references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to copy/move data first into `this` sub-object and then use it to initialize the other base class sub-objects.

Example:

```
class ConcreteClass
    : private Data // Must be inherited first.
    , public BaseClassA
    , public BaseClassB
{
public:
    ConcreteClass(Data&& data)
        : Data(std::move(data))
        , BaseClassA(getData())
        , BaseClassB(getData())
    {}

    /* Class functions here */

private:
    Data const& getData() const { return *this; }
};
```

This is a well-known idiom, see [`boost::base_from_member`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/utility/doc/html/base_from_member.html) for more details.